# How to access variables when dealing with file system?

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, filesystems

```
var fs = require('fs');

for(var x = 0; x < 10; x++){
    fs.open("file.txt", 'a',function(err, fd){
        if(!err){
            fs.write(fd, x.toString() + "\n");
        }

    });
}
```

This prints out a bunch of 10s. I made the program to print out 0-9. For some reason, the code inside fs.open cannot access the x variable correctly. Can anybody explain? Is there an issue with scope?

Comment: take the `var` out of `var x` to change the scope of `x`

Comment: That did not help. it still prints out only 10s.

Comment: @mike.k: JavaScript `var` doesn't have block scope.

Comment: read the dupe, it has the answer.